# Confused about BinarySearch after Reverse

Tags: c#, binary-search

I want to find an element index in a descending order list, but BinarySearch returns a negative number. Why is it so? Here is my code snippet:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(4);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Sort();
list.Reverse();
var elementIndex = list.BinarySearch(5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the default comparer, which expects that the list will be sorted   **only** in ascending order. If you want to use BinarySearch on a list sorted in descending order, you should implement IComparer interface. For example:

```
class ReverseComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

And then pass it as a parameter to the method:

```
...
var elementIndex = list.BinarySearch(5, new ReverseComparer());
```